# Deleting rows in a tableview with section headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before adding section headers to one of my tables in my app, I was able to delete rows using the commitEditingStyle function. I decided to implement section headers to make it easier for the user to view items added to the table by date. I tested this functionality and it works fine. But now trying to delete a row causes a crash:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], >/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:1330

I am new to obj-c development and was reluctant to add the sections since I knew it would add more complexity to the code, and it took me a while to figure it out. But I guess that's the way you learn.

Here is the code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AgendaCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AgendaCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *strDate = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *dateSection = [tempDict objectForKey:strDate];

    NSManagedObject *object = [dateSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.sessionNameLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"sessionname"];
    cell.sessionNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.sessionDateLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"sessiondate"];
    cell.sessionDateLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    cell.sessionTimeLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"sessiontime"];
    cell.sessionTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    return cell;

}
```

Here is the code for my table refresh function:

```
- (void) refreshTable
    {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sessnotes"   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"agenda == 'Yes'"]];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]  initWithKey:@"sessiondate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

     NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest   error:nil];

        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        self.objects = results;

    if (results.count == 0) {
        NSString *message = @"You have not added any sessions to your planner.";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification"
                                                       message:message
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else if (results.count > 0){
    tempDict = nil;
    tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *strPrevDate= [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"sessiondate"];
    NSLog(@"strPrevDate value is: %@", strPrevDate);
    NSString *strCurrDate = nil;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Add the Similar Date data in An Array then add this array to Dictionary
    //With date name as a Key. It helps to easily create section in table.
    for(int i=0; i< [results count]; i++)
    {
        strCurrDate = [[results objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"sessiondate"];

        if ([strCurrDate isEqualToString:strPrevDate])
        {
            [tempArray addObject:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else
        {
            [tempDict setValue:[tempArray copy] forKey:strPrevDate];

            strPrevDate = strCurrDate;
            [tempArray removeAllObjects];
            [tempArray addObject:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    //Set the last date array in dictionary
    [tempDict setValue:[tempArray copy] forKey:strPrevDate];

    NSArray *tArray = [tempDict allKeys];
    //Sort the array in ascending order
    dateArray = [tArray    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here is the code for the commitEditingStyle function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete

        NSManagedObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        [context deleteObject:[context objectWithID:[object objectID]]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSMutableArray *array = [self.objects mutableCopy];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.objects = array;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more of the crash information?

Comment: If you're using Core Data then you should really be using an NSFetchedResultsController. Take a look at this... http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//replace with it:
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Or the slightly less nuclear option (more localized animation) `[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]`

Comment: Thanks. So the above works when deleting rows with different header sections (although the header sections remain until I refresh the table then they do not show). However, if the rows are in the same section and I try to delete more than one row in sequence beginning with the top row in the section, the top row deletes fine but trying to delete the second row causes the app to crash. If I delete all rows in sequence other than the first row and then delete the first row last, it works fine. Any help with this?

Comment: That resolved the crash and mess but I had to give up the nice insert/delete animations so still looking for a better solution.